# How to return Http Status and then start other route process in CAMEL

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel, synchronization

how can I return a response with http status and then, start a syn process in camel?

flow:

receive a request;
return http status 200 only to informate that I got the request correctly;
start a route with a sync process.

the objective is return fast the response with http Status but foward do a serie of integrations

Comment: Take a look at WireTap EIP pattern

Comment: thks @ClausIbsen, only another questions... After response the HttpStatus, I need to start a serie of routes, but these routes need to be sync, they are dependents, is this possible?
I am using spring + camel

Comment: You can use direct component to call between routes synchronously